# Image segmentation of objects in any illumination(low or high)

Tags: python-3.x, opencv, image-processing, image-segmentation

The problem I have at hand is to draw boundaries around a white ball. But the ball is present in different illuminations. Using canny edge detections and Hough transform for circles, I am able to detect the ball in bright light/partial bright light but not in low illumination.

So can anyone help with this problem.
The code that I have tried is below.

```
img=cv2.imread('14_04_2018_10_38_51_.8242_P_B_142_17197493.png.png')
cimg=img.copy()
img = cv2.cvtColor(img,cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
edges = cv2.medianBlur(img,5)
edges=cv2.Canny(edges,200,200)
circles = cv2.HoughCircles(edges,cv2.HOUGH_GRADIENT,1,20,
                        param1=25,param2=10,minRadius=0,maxRadius=0)

if circles is not None:
     circles = np.uint16(np.around(circles))
     for i in circles[0,:]:
         # draw the outer circle
         cv2.circle(cimg,(i[0],i[1]),i[2],(255,255,255),2)
         # draw the center of the circle
         cv2.circle(cimg,(i[0],i[1]),2,(0,0,255),3)
     cv2.imwrite('segmented_out.png',cimg)
else:
    print("no circles")
cv2.imwrite('edges_out.png',edges)
```

In the image below we need to segment if the ball is in the shadow region as well.

[image: input image]

The output should be something like below images..

[image: output]

Comment: Add the input image and your results.

Comment: @zindarod I cannot put the original images for confidential reasons. However I will try to put something close to what I'm trying.

Answer (score 2):

Well I am not very experienced in OpenCV or Python but I am learning as well. Probably not very pythonic piece of code but you could try this:

```
import cv2
import math

circ=0
n = [10, 20, 30, 40, 50, 60, 70, 80, 90, 100, 110, 120, 130, 140, 150, 160, 170, 180, 190, 200, 210, 220]
img = cv2.imread("ball1.jpg")
gray = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
for i in n:   
    ret, threshold = cv2.threshold(gray,i,255,cv2.THRESH_BINARY)
    im, contours, hierarchy = cv2.findContours(threshold,cv2.RETR_TREE,cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_NONE)
    for j in range(0, len(contours)):
        size = cv2.contourArea(contours[j])
        if 500 < size < 5000:
            if circ > 0:
                (x,y),radius = cv2.minEnclosingCircle(contours[j])
                radius = int(radius)
                area = cv2.contourArea(contours[j])
                circif = 4*area/(math.pi*(radius*2)**2)
                if circif > circ:
                    circ = float(circif)
                    radiusx = radius
                    center = (int(x),int(y))                  
            elif circ == 0:
                (x,y),radius = cv2.minEnclosingCircle(contours[j])
                radius = int(radius)
                area = cv2.contourArea(contours[j])
                circ = 4*area/(math.pi*(radius*2)**2)
            else:
                pass
cv2.circle(img,center,radiusx,(0,255,0),2)
cv2.imshow('image', img)
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.detroyAllWindows()
```

What it does is acctually you convert your picture to grayscale and apply different threshold settings to it. Then you eliminate noises with adding size to your specific contour. When you find it, you check its circularity (NOTE: it is not a scientific formula) and compare it to the next circularity. Perfect circle should return the result 1, so the highest number that will get in a contour (of all the contours) will be your ball.

Result:

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

NOTE: I haven't tried increasing the limit of size so maybe higher limit could return better result if you have a high resolution picture

Comment: Is this what you refer to as "it is not a scientific formula"? `circ = 4*area/(math.pi*(radius*2)**2)` -- You might as well ignore the constants is you are just looking for the largest value of circularity: `circ = area/(radius**2)`. Otherwise, `area=2*pi*radius**2` for a circle, so `circ = area/(2*pi*radius**2)` would be more correct. There are other roundness criteria that might work better. For example, if you can compute the perimeter, then `circ = 4*pi*area/(perimeter**2)` is a good one. It is 1 for a perfect circle, and smaller for less circular shapes.

Comment: I have found a bug in the code...I updated and it should work better now. It should be "if circif > circ: circ = float(corcif)"  @Cris Luengo: I belive that there are better algorithms for circularity (I am not a mathematician) but tried your formula and mine with a white rectangle added to picture and in your case it selected the rectangle (although I tried it after the update in formula)

Comment: Do you mean the one with the perimeter? How did you compute the perimeter? Counting border pixels is not a good estimate of the perimeter, a square will have a similar perimeter to a circle. See [here](https://www.crisluengo.net/index.php/archives/310) for a good way to estimate perimeter.

Comment: Also note that `4*area/(math.pi*(radius*2)**2) == area/(math.pi*(radius)**2)`.

Comment: Yeah you are probbably right. I tried it with cv2.arcLength(cnt,True) for perimeter. But I think that for this purpose it should work just fine:)

Comment: Thanks btw for the link...it's very good and will study it for future computing!

Answer (score 1):

Working with `grayscale` image will make you subject to different light conditions.

To be free from this I suggest to work in `HSV` color space, then use the `Hue` component instead of the `grayscale` image.

Hue is independent from the light condition, since it gives you information about the color, regardless of its `Saturation` or `Value` (a value bound to the brightness of the image).

[This](https://www.learnopencv.com/color-spaces-in-opencv-cpp-python/) might bring you some clarity about color spaces and which is best to use for image segmentation.

Comment: thanks. It was certainly the lines I was thinking. But what if the image has only shades of gray although it is not a grayscale image.

Comment: Then you are prisoner of the brightness I guess, since grayscale is, by definition, an average of the three channels RGB, which depend on brightness.

Answer (score 0):

In your case here. We have a white ball.
`White` is not a color by itself.
The main factor here is, what kind light actually falls on the `white ball`
As the kind of light that falls on it has a direct influence on the kind of extraction you might plan to do using a `color space` like HSV as mentioned above by @magicleon

`HSV` is your best bet for segmentation here.
Using
`whiteObject = cv2.inRange(hsvImage,lowerHSVLimit,upperHSVLimit)`

`lowerHSVLimit` and `upperHSVLimit` HSV color range

Keeping in mind that the conditions
 
1) The image have similar conditions while they were clicked

2) You cover all the ranges of HSV before extraction

Hope you get an idea

Consider this example

[image]

Selecting a particular `hue` range from `45` to `60`

Code

```
image = cv2.imread('allcolors.png')

hsvImg = cv2.cvtColor(image,cv2.COLOR_BGR2HSV)

lowerHSVLimit = np.array([45,0,0])
upperHSVLimit = np.array([60,255,255])

colour = cv2.inRange(hsvImg,lowerHSVLimit,upperHSVLimit)

plt.subplot(111), plt.imshow(colour,cmap="gray")
plt.title('hue range from 45 to 60'), plt.xticks([]), plt.yticks([])
plt.show()
```

Here the hue selected from `45` to `60`

[image]

Comment: I did not understand the piece of code you wrote there. Can you put a word or two in explanation?

Comment: Thanks. I liked your answer and its rather straight forward. But again considering image I have put, what if the white golf ball is in the shadow of the golf bat. Then what will be hsv values you will choose??

Comment: Hope [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HSL_and_HSV#/media/File:HSV_color_solid_cylinder_alpha_lowgamma.png) gives you an idea